# Only deployed pages do not retry existing requests after token re-issuance via React Axios Interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Through the code below, we tried to reissue the token through the React Axios Interceptor and retry the existing request that was denied due to the token expiration.
When testing on local host, requests that were buffered while the token was refreshed work well again after the access token was reissued, but not on the distributed page.
Can't I access the error's config in the https environment?

```
let isTokenRefreshing = false;
const refreshSubscribers = [];

const onTokenRefreshed = accessToken => {

    refreshSubscribers.map(callback => {
        callback(accessToken);
    });
};

const addRefreshSubscriber = callback => {
    refreshSubscribers.push(callback);
};

AxiosInterceptor.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response;
    },
    async error => {

        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {

            const originalRequest = error.config;

            if (isTokenRefreshing === false) {

                isTokenRefreshing = true;

                const tokenData = await localStorage.getItem('token');
                const { refreshToken } = JSON.parse(tokenData);
    
                try {
                    const resp = await axios.post(
                        `refresh token api url`,
                        null,
                        {
                            params: { refreshToken },
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: null,
                            },
                        },
                    );


                    if (parseInt(resp.status / 200, 10) === 1) {
                        await localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(resp.data));

                        isTokenRefreshing = false;

                        axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${resp.data.accessToken}`;

                        onTokenRefreshed(resp.data.accessToken);

                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    if (e.response.status === 401) {
                        localStorage.clear();
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            }
            const retryOriginalRequest = new Promise(resolve => {
                addRefreshSubscriber(accessToken => {
                    originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
                    resolve(axios(originalRequest));
                });
            });
            return retryOriginalRequest;
        }

        return error;
    },
);
```

I want to know why it works well in a local host environment, but it doesn't work well in a deployed environment.